# Is "on an elevator" a common US usage?

Tags: american-english

Twice in the book I'm currently reading (and I believe elsewhere occasionally) I've seen "*on an elevator*" where I (in the UK) would expect "***in** an elevator*".  Is "on" a common American usage (the rest of the book uses US spellings) or are they just typos / odd usage by the author?

I searched, but the only reference I could find was [this question on another website](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WhichRightElevatorElevator/brmdnz/post.htm) which basically says "in" all the time.

The book in question is *The Atlantis Gene (Origin Mystery, Book 1)* by A.G.Riddle.  The relevant excerpts (my emphasis) are:

> Message: We were getting water together at the desk and got **on the
>   elevator** together.  Didn't know if you wanted to get together for a
>   little extra exercise. Tell what floor I got off on.
>
> `Page 86; Kindle location 1353`

and:

> **On the elevator**, Kate had fought at the guards' vice-grip hold on her
>   arms.  They pinned her to the wall until the elevator doors opened,...
>
> `Page 133; Kindle location 2036`

On searching for the above, I also found:

> Josh felt his mouth go dry. "That's why you grabbed me **off the
>   elevator**."
>
> `Page 48; Kindle location 749`

where pulling someone "off" an elevator corresponds to them being "on" it beforehand (I'd probably have used "from" or "out of").  However, elsewhere there is:

> Martin stepped **out of the elevator** onto the helipad.
>
> `Page 128; Kindle location 1970`

rather than "stepped off the elevator".

Comment: I suppose if my wife called me on my cellphone and asked where I was, I would likely reply "in an elevator", if indeed I was.  But I think most people in the US who read "on an elevator" rather than "in an elevator" would think nothing was particularly strange about it.

Comment: That seems to be talking more about when board/aboard is appropriate (although the second answer does mention "get into an elevator"). My question is more about once you _are_ in/on the elevator.

Comment: Perhaps the preposition "on" would be used more frequently in reference to one's location ON an ESCALATOR than ON an elevator, but frankly, I don't think any Americans would bust your chops for saying, "I was on an elevator going down, when suddenly the power went out and the elevator came to a standstill."  A strict grammarian might, but who takes a strict grammarian seriously? Don

Comment: I think most in the US would refer to *getting on* an elevator, when boarding, but when riding they would most likely describe themselves as *in* the elevator.  And there's nothing grammatically wrong with either construction.

Comment: In the past, I have also asked about questions about expressions that I was unfamiliar with,  but I always included the citation, [the title of the book, and, sometimes,  its page](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44619+apple+tree+yard). You're going to have to do the same if you want somebody to answer the question title.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know what you are trying to do with the comment. But I think your wording doesn't serve the purpose. Can you just go easy with your comment? You could have said, "it is recommendable to include the citation in your question ." You sound like nobody will answer this question unless citation is included. Do you really think citation is absolutely necessary for this simple and popular expression?

Comment: In response to a comment left by Rathony, I will say this. This question was asked seven hours ago, it has received only one answer which is answering a different question. The OP writes *I'm currently reading*, so it shouldn't be too difficult to cite, at the very least, the title of the book. My comment is aimed to help the OP's question get more attention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It might not be too difficult for you. But for some people, they wouldn't want to do it because they feel it is not that necessary and can be waste of time. Why do you think the below answer is answering a different quesiton?

Comment: I'll add the book and some quotes when i get in front of a PC in an hour or so. I had considered whether or not to do so when I asked the question, but decided not to, to save the author's blushes if the response had been "nobody writes like that".

Comment: @TripeHound No worry. Nobody writes like that here.

Comment: Perfectly normal usage IMO,  to "get on" a *vehicle* that moves seems fine to me, I was thinking the examples were quite different e,g, "We were talking on the elevator..." etc.. that kind of thing. And I would have said "lift" is far more common in BrEng.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I think the conclusion is that it's a normal phrasing in US-English whereas (unless it's just me) British English would use "in".  (Also, I was ignoring the elevator/lift aspect as that's a "known" difference).

Comment: OP: Do you have the same question about *get on/in the bus/plane*? From where I sit, both *on* and *in* can be used in these cases, though they can have slightly different connotations. I would probably always say *get on the train* but I might say, in some contexts *get in the train car*. It's all about whether you are thinking of the destination as a container, IMO. We pretty much always say *get in the car* (container), and *get on the train* (not a single container, but as @Rathony says, a conveyance), but we can say both *get in the plane* and *get on the plane*.

Comment: @Drew  In most/nearly all cases, I think I'd say _on_ a bus/plane (which fits with it being a "means of conveyance"). Like you, I might say _I'm in the carriage [train car]_, but this would be in contrast to being outside the carriage, in a spatial/contained-or-not sense. Most of the time, I think _plane_ would fit in the same category. I think the difference with lift/elevator is that for me (and possibly other Brits) is that (probably unconsciously) I don't think of it as a "means of conveyance" in that sense.  Yes it "conveys" you between floors, but in a different way to a bus across town.

Comment: @TripeHound: Precisely. It depends how you are considering the thing you are getting onto/into.

Comment: *where I (in the UK) would expect "in an elevator".* You should expect *"in a lift".*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualitatively, 'in' usually is used for the metaphor of being within a surrounding structure, like a room or enclosure.

And 'on' is usually used for the metaphor of taking the conveyance (or more literally being on the top of a surface).

For example, being 'in a train' implies being inside a train car, being 'on a train' implies traveling using a train (or could mean you're traveling literally on the mostly flat roof of the train).

An elevator shares this ambiguity. 'In an elevator' is inside the box-like enclosure of the conveyance. 'On an elevator' is *using* the conveyence, like 'on a train, boat, plane'.

---

Also, note that 'lift' is a synonym for 'elevator' in the UK, where it is not at all in the US.

---

So as to frequency, a good quantitative, data driven comparison can be done using [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

First let's look at the 8 possibilities of 'in' vs 'on', 'elevator' vs 'lift', US vs UK

[Frequency of 'in' and 'on' an 'elevator' and 'lift' in US and UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+an+elevator%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+an+elevator%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+an+elevator%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Con+an+elevator%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cin+a+lift%3Aeng_us_2012%2Con+a+lift%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+a+lift%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Con+a+lift%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: Google ngram of Frequencies of 'in' and 'on', 'elevator' and 'lift' in US and UK]

First this confirms that 'lift' is rare in the US (the context for 'in a lift' seems likely to mean only as a synonym for elevator). Also, it is interesting to note that 'lift' and 'elevator' in the UK are mostly the same.

I interpret the graph to simply mean that, whether in or on an elevator, such statements are much more common in the US than in the UK. But eyeballing the relative frequencies, it looks roughly the same, that 'in' is used a lot more than 'on', whether restricted to the US or to the UK.

Fortunately, NGrams has some syntax to take ratios of two frequencies. This allows us to compare the ratio of 'in' to 'on' for elevators. Maybe Americans use 'on' much more frequently than 'in'. Also, to simplify, let's stick to elevator for the US ('lift' is so rare) and 'lift' for the UK (since it is roughly the same as 'elevator'):

[Ratio of 'in' to 'on' a lift in UK vs an elevator in US](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+an+elevator%3Aeng_us_2012%2Fon+an+elevator%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cin+a+lift%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Fon+a+lift%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: ratios]

The ratios change over time, and between the US and UK, they cross a few times.

Considering after 1960, when they don't cross over so much, the UK favors 'in' to 'on' *much* more than the US does. So it is not surprising that when a BrE speaker visits the US, the few times more that people say 'on' in AmE might stand out

So, nowadays, to corroborate your feeling, **the US is actually using 'on' more *with respect to 'in'* than in the UK**. But in both places 'in' is still used more than 'on'. just not as much in the US.

Note: corpus searches like these have all sorts of caveats: mis-labelings of sources to UK or US, dates, but mostly fears of catching text with those searches that are not what you expected. I think that the complete prepositional phrase is long enough and not needing any context, to avoid most problems. If there are conflicting contexts or alternate terms that you can think of, they are welcome.

Comment: Great research. So the simple answer is: both US and UK tend to use "in" more than "on"; _I'm_ more used to "in"; the author happens to use "on". Might be interesting to see how "in/on a _lift_" fares in UK texts.

Comment: @TripeHound Urgh. The 'I didn't think of that' rears its ugly head. That's the problem, setting up the problem correctly to begin with. 'lift' is not used at all in the US (at least not for elevator). So a quick look shows that, yes, 'on the lift' is hardly used in the UK, so the ration of 'on' to 'in' is way in favor of 'in' in the UK. I'll update soon

Comment: "We have really everything in common with America nowadays, except, of course, language." Oscar Wilde, _The Canterville Ghost_

Answer (score 2):

I believe there has to be a reason why people use "on" instead of "in" when talking about a place they are "in", for example, we use more on the bus, on the train, on the ship, and even on the space shuttle, etc. than "in".

According to Merriam-Webster, [on is used as a function word to indicate means of conveyance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)

But strangely, in a (the) car is more used than on a (the) car. (Do I need to put Ngram here?)

I think the reason is that the car or the truck you are "in" is not moving at the time of speaking. You say "I am driving" rather than "I am in a car" when the car is "conveying you".

Comment: This seems to nicely capture why some things are "on" and others "in" (I'd be happy with all of "_on the bus, on the train, on the ship_").  Maybe it's just difference as to whether an elevator counts as a "conveyance" or not?

Comment: @TripeHound If you hear someone say you have to use "in" when an elevator is not moving and "on" when it is conveying you, you would  think he/she is crazy. "I am in an elevator" sounds perfectly fine even if it is moving. I go to school by bus. You use "by" here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as an American, I would use both. I might also say "I'm on a ferris wheel." or "I'm on a roller coaster." Perhaps being "on a ride" is what comes to mind when I think of that phrasing, so it also makes sense in my mind (on my mind? maybe you're on my mind!) regarding an elevator - a type of "ride". "I ride on the elevator". "I ride on the escalator", etc. Or even just "I ride the elevator/ferris wheel/roller coaster/escalator..."

One can also "take" the elevator, but that's whole nother question (as is "nother", lol).

Answer (score -1):

If you're standing or are allowed to stand then its always "on". For example, on the train, on the bus, on the plane. While one can't travel standing in a Car so its always in the car. 
So technically it should be "on an elevator".

Comment: While this seems to be handy rule of thumb, do you have any sources to bolster it's accuracy?